# Motronic 1.0 component identification

Tags: transistors

Trying to identify a transistor, <s>ON698</s>   6N608 ? GR608 ?
part of ignition coil driver circuit on Motronic 1.0 dme on 80's BMW or Porche
                    [image: enter image description here] part of ignition coil driver circuit on motronic 1.0 dme [![https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx2g5.jpg]

Hard to read ??

Comment: It's an ON608. What is your question? Please note that direct shopping questions will result in fairly prompt closure of your question as per [site rules](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Transistor I think they want a datasheet? A brief search doesn't turn much up.

Comment: use isopropanol (alcohol) to remove the black mark ..... test on 3rd row print first

Answer (score 2):

Corrected part number is 6N60  with bin 8 tolerance

6N60 MOSFET.

Type Designator: 6N60
Type of Transistor: MOSFET
Type of Control Channel: N -Channel
Maximum Power Dissipation (Pd): 125 W
Maximum Drain-Source Voltage |Vds|: 600 V
Maximum Gate-Source Voltage |Vgs|: 30 V
Maximum Drain Current |Id|: 6.2 A
Maximum Junction Temperature (Tj): 150 °C
Rise Time (tr): 70 nS
Drain-Source Capacitance (Cd): 95 pF
Maximum Drain-Source On-State Resistance (Rds): 1 Ohm
Package: TO-220_TO-251_TO-252_TO-220F_TO-220F1_TO-263

Datasheets of found equiv , not verified
https://alltransistors.com/mosfet/transistor.php?transistor=19485

The key parameters for a fuel injector power FET are low RdsOn, good heatsink, low pF. 
This old class of Nch FETs had a threshold of 2~4V meaning a Vs(th)=3V+/-1V

- [Fuji Power](https://alltransistors.com/pdfdatasheet_upd-mosfet/fmi16n60e.pdf) FMI 16N60E offers better tolerances 3V +/-0.5V and lower RdsOn at Vgs=10V than original part

## techie details

The (8) suffix printed on would indicate some sorted value for maximum Ron=Rds=RdsOn at some Vgs like 10V which is usually 3x Vgs(th) but just best guess. Considering these were newly developed technology from companies like International Rectifier the tolerances and defect rates were higher than mature modern parts.

The existing part is called a TO-5 is obsolete for these part types and a better case is the  TO-220. The former heatsink in an open air might be 40'C/W in open convection, but higher inside an enclosed case.  At a minimum, the equivalent heatsink size is shown below for a TO-220 in low profile.  Kapton Tape or equiv insulation tape may be needed to prevent shorting exposed conductors. The PCB holes would need to be enlarged for TO-220 pins and paths resoldered.

[image]

Overall debug  http://www.hiperformancestore.com/motronic.htm

Comment: Wait a minute, *6*N? Doesn't that mean it should have six pn junctions?

Comment: Hex = 6N  really?  because FMI's part is 16N

Comment: The original meaning of the number before the N was the number of junctions in the device. Thus diodes get 1N, transistors get 2N, thyristors are 3N, and you sometimes see 4N or 5N for some optocouplers. The _original_ original meaning was the voltage rating of the filament, but as that doesn't apply to semiconductor devices the field in the part number was repurposed.

Comment: I'm also not too convinced this is the right part. Was the 6N60 ever produced in a TO-5 package? I can't find any datasheets that say it was.

Comment: I used logic in my search... using ?N60  6 is the most likely value for automotive fuel injectors rated at high voltage , current and speed.  and are still used today with enhanced performance.  The last digit (8) is an obvious binned screen value which has TBD meaning

Comment: HEXFET's were introduced in mid-80's when Bosch designed these ECU's (DME)  Typical modern Power MOSFETs have millions of
identical trenches, cells or many strips in parallel to
form one device,

Comment: thanks guys i appreciate ur help, but after testing the transistor  was found to be good.

Answer (score 2):

I´ve visited with a great delay - maybe somebody will used the following information fo another purpose. ON608 is the Philips in-house sign for the NPN transistor BSX46/16. In the automotive ECUs have been used in 90s the discrete transistors for switching purpose. So you can use an suitable equivalent with hFE of about of 200, Icmax not smaller 1A and Ptot of similar value (5W).
Good luck and nice time!   Vl.